# Cleaning ~/.prefect/pg_data/ when using Prefect

Tags: python, postgresql, prefect

I'm using **Prefect** to automatize my flows (python scripts). Once running, some data get persisted to a postgresql database, problem, the size of pg_data gets rapidely out of hands (~20Gb) and I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the amount of data stored to pg_data when running an agent or if there was a way to automatically clean the directory.

Thanks in advance for your help,

best,

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running Prefect Server and you want to clean up the underlying database instance to save space? If so, there are a couple of ways you can clean up the Postgres database:

- you can manually delete old records, especially logs from the flow run table using DELETE FROM in SQL,
- you can do the same in an automated fashion, e.g. some users have an actual flow that runs on schedule and purges old data from the database,
- alternatively, you can use the open-source [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) job scheduler for Postgres to schedule such DB administration tasks,
- you can also do the same using GraphQL: you would need to query for flow run IDs of "old" flow runs using the `flow_run` query, and then execute `delete_flow_run` mutation,
- lastly, to be more proactive, you can reduce the number of logs you generate by generally logging less (only logging what's needed) and setting the log level to a lower category, e.g. instead of using DEBUG logs on your agent, switching to INFO should significantly reduce the amount of space consumed by logs in the database.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for all these suggestions, for now I just did a manual deletion, which is needed every 2 months or so. The option where I schedule a purger using a prefect flow is probably the best. I'll try these things out :)

Comment: For posterity, also sharing an alternative solution available on [Prefect Discourse](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-can-i-delete-old-flow-runs-older-than-30-days-using-graphql-api-to-clean-up-database-space-in-prefect-server/136)